# SQL join 2 tables where date columns match

Tags: mysql, join

I have got 2 tables, both tables have a date column - what I want to do is join the tables if the rows dates match.

I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM bats 
  LEFT 
  JOIN weather 
    ON 'weather.GMT' = 'bats.startDate'
```

This joins the tables into a new table with all the values of the bats but null values for the weather.

What I want is the following, as an example:

```
observationID   |  startDate | commonName |    GMT    | WindSpeed | Event | Temp
------------------------------------------------------------------
       1            12/12/2001       Natterer        12/12/2001       25         Rain
       2            13/12/2001       Brown Eared     13/12/2001       12        Cloudy
      Null             Null             Null         14/12/2001       14         Rain
```

The above joining of the tables is where there will always be 1 entry for the weather table, but could be 1, none or several entries for the bat table.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Kevin

Comment: Just swap the place of `bat` and `weather` in your join: `SELECT * FROM weather LEFT OUTER JOIN bats ON 'weather.GMT' = 'bats.startDate'`

Comment: 'weather.GMT' is a string. And a result set with no data set is like a stick without a lollipop. No fun at all.

Comment: This query is being generated through an ipython notebook, I did try without the quotes originally and it kept giving me an error message that the columns don't exist. That's why I tried it with the quotes and it did produce a table, just not the table format that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You did it in the other way around, try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM weather AS w
LEFT JOIN bats AS b ON (w.GMT = b.startDate)
```

BTW, please avoid uppercases in the column names and always use underscore for the spaces, it's the convention :)

Comment: I have tried this Juan and the same result only in reverse, the weather data is present and the bat data is all none. I think this query requires something a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the comment by Strawberry

> 'weather.GMT' is a string

Swap the 's for `s (the key above Tab) and you'll be away laughing. Alternatively you could also just remove the quote marks like in Juan Alberto's answer and that will work too. You only need to use back quotes (`) if you have a space in your column name